# how to get information about discounts on product?

Tags: commerce, rules

Short: I have commerce product and commerce discount that affects this product's price. I want to presents details of this discount to users in shop.

Long story: I use Drupal Commerce with Drupal Commerce Discount which is based on Rules. Discount module is used for configuring promotions on products. Some of promotion (configured discounts) are time-limited ie. they ends on 11.11.2015. 
I would like to get information about discounts that affect product when displaying details. First of all I need to display information how much time is left before discount ends.

Is there any way to get information about active rules on product level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the line item, you have the `field_unit_price` field. Inside of that field's data attribute, you'll find information about the discounts that are applied to that product:

```
array(1) {
  ["components"]=>
  array(2) {
    ...
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(22) "discount|discount_test"
      ["price"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["amount"]=>
        float(-240)
        ["currency_code"]=>
        string(3) "USD"
        ["data"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["discount_name"]=>
          string(13) "discount_test"
          ["discount_component_title"]=>
          string(5) "Test"
        }
      }
      ["included"]=>
      bool(true)
    }
  }
}
```

Iterate over the components. If there is a discount applied to one of the items, you'll find one with a name that begins with `discount|`.  Then you can then load that discount and grab more information about it:

```
$discount = entity_load('commerce_discount', array('discount_test'));
```

From here, if you've added dates, the date fields will be accessible on the field `commerce_discount_date`.